# What is wrong with this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, limits, functions

I have a function

> $$f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$$

while solving this simply I get $f(1)=3,f(2)=\frac00,f(3)=5,\cdots$ the problem is when I solve this simply I get $$f(x)=x+2$$ and then I found except $f(2)$ all the values were same. Can someone help me where I did the mistake?

Comment: You might find [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2085545/276406) to be particularly helpful.  In a nutshell, you've changed the *implicit* domain so you need to *explicitly* specify that the domain has not changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cancel $x-2$ then you have to give the condition$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$$ $$f(x)=\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{(x-2)}$$ now you have to write $$f(x)=x+2\tag{where $x\ne2$}$$