# continuity and not-continuous

Tags: continuity

I am currently working on continuity of functions and I just red that the composition of two not-continuous can be continous. Currently I can't imagine why this is the case and can someone give me an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any non-continuous function $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ that takes values in the set $[0,1]$.  For instance:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is even}\\
1&\text{if $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Now take a non-continuous function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that is constant on $[0,1]$.  For instance:
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if $0\le x \le 1$}\\
1&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The composition of these two functions will be constant and therefore continuous.  For example, the composition $g\circ f$ is the constant function $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} 5, & x < 3 \\
7 , & x \ge 3 \end{cases}$, then $f(f(x)) = 7$

Answer (score 0):

Often discontinuities arise from division by 0. So, for example $f(x) = g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ gives $f \circ g = x$ which is continuous.

Comment: No, this would still have a discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: $f(g(x)) = \frac{1}{1/x} = x$... has a discontinuity at $x = 0$?

Comment: Yes.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2085521/276406 and related questions.  The domain of a function does not change simply by algebraic manipulation; in this case it changes from being *implicit* to requiring an *explicit* statement that $x$ may not equal $0$.

Comment: Oh. Yeah you're right. Instead define it piecewise, $f(x) = g(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ otherwise--then it satisfies OP's conditions.