# Determine the set of definitions of the function $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-5x+6}}{|2x-1|}$

Tags: functions

I got this function, but I do not know how to approach the problem at all. Can someone guide me?

> Determine the set of definitions of the function:
> $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-5x+6}}{|2x-1|}$$

---

Example

Let $f : [0,\infty) \to\Bbb{R}$ be a function by given formula
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2)}$$
The aswer would be $$[0, \infty) \subseteq \Bbb{R}\setminus\{−1, −2\}$$

Comment: What does "Determine the set of definitions of a function" mean?  Can you give a simple example?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I've added simple example with answer which seems easy, but I don't know how to solve the first function at all.

Comment: Did you mean "find range and domain" of the function?

Comment: @lonestudent I think so, I might've translated it wrong

Comment: @lonestudent Relevant? '[How do you prove the domain of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856226/how-do-you-prove-the-domain-of-a-function)'

Comment: the function is not defined for any $x$ in the set $(2,3)\cup\{1/2\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to determine the domain of $f$, you need to determine all values where $f$ is **not** well-defined. Concretely, this means checking the values where you might accidentally divide by 0 or get negative values under a square root. Let's begin by assuming that the domain $D_0$ of $f$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

We see that $|2x-1|=0$ if and only if $x=\frac12$, so we exclude this number and now have that our domain is $D_1 := \mathbb{R} \setminus \{\frac12\}$. Next, you can check for yourself that $x^2-5x+6<0$ if and only if $2<x<3$. For these values of $x$, the term $\sqrt{x^2-5x+6}$ is not defined, so we will exclude these values from the domain as well. Hence, our domain is now $D_2 := \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ \{\frac12\} \cup (2,3) \}$. Since for all values in $D_2$ the function $f$ is well-defined, $D_2$ is the domain of $f$ that was to be determined. Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't understand where did you get the `2<x<3` from

Comment: Hint: $x^2-5x+6 = (x-2)(x-3)$. Alternatively, you can plot this function to get an idea what I'm talking about.